# Как создать файл в папке?

Tags: java

Папка расположена по пути `Path`.

Answer (score 3):

Вроде как-то так:

```
String pathToFile = "ПУТЬ_К_ВАШЕЙ_ПАПКЕ" + "YOURS_FILE_NAME.txt";
File file = new File(pathToFile);
file.mkdirs();

try
{
    // открываем поток для записи
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    // пишем данные
    bw.write("НЕКИЕ_СТРОКОВЫЕ_ДАННЫЕ");
    // закрываем поток
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так папка создаётся

Comment: Обновил ответ.